# event not trigger on cordova file downlaod

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am testing Cordova file download, but cant see it calling from chrome.
My code is :

```
 $scope.uploadEvent= function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    window.addEventListener('filePluginIsReady',onDeviceReady , false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
      // File for download
```

cant see any errors on console.
I am using [cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file)

Comment: can you post your complete HTML code? Have you included cordova.js file in your HTML?

Comment: post your complete HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use ngCordova [`$cordovaFileTransfer`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) instead ([install ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) before you use it).

Sample download approach:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

    var url = "http://cdn.wall-pix.net/albums/art-space/00030109.jpg";
    var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "testImage.png";
    var trustHosts = true;
    var options = {};

    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
      .then(function(result) {
        // Success!
      }, function(err) {
        // Error
      }, function (progress) {
        $timeout(function () {
          $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
        });
      });

   }, false);
}
```

Comment: tryed to do this with  window.addEventListener('filePluginIsReady', function(){  but still same issue...